# Pluggin Unity Game into a existing Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, frameworks

I am looking into a AR game to plug into my current App. My app currently has a Game developed using SpriteKit.

I am looking to develop a more complex game but would like to use Unity Engine as it will allow for cross platform compatibility with Android.

Any tips or information regarding how to go about inserting a unity game into a existing Xcode project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid what you want is not possible. Unity project is like 'master' project and you can only plug ios libraries to Unity project, not vice versa. Also, you are talking about Android compability. How would you like your game to be run on Android if you will have whole project in xcode?

Comment: The project would be developed in Xcode and Android Studio, then a unity game to be plugged into both projects was the idea.

Comment: Okay, but still, Unity project is 'master', as described in the article: "The easiest way is to start your native app from the unity-generated XCode Project". But, anyways, you have a guide in this article. And when it comes to Android it might be not that easy because Unity generates .apk. Don't know how could you possibly 'plug' it.